# sh: /usr/bin/pdftk: No such file or directory

Tags: php, pdf, cakephp-3.0, pdftk, php-pdftk

I am trying to extract PDF form details using [PDFTK](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) sever but I am getting an error `sh: /usr/bin/pdftk: No such file or directory` when executing from PHP with help of `exec` and `exec_shell` both function. I tried with full path but still shows me the same error.

I have tried with setting envput() function but no luck.

below is command which is executing from PHP `exec` and `exec_shell` functions, this command worked expected when execute it from terminal (OS : CentOS).

```
/usr/bin/pdftk /home/www/public_html/webroot/tmp/client_import_form_filled.pdf dump_data_fields_utf8 2>&1
```

I am expecting PDF form extracted data as below

```
FieldType: Text
FieldName: ClientFirstName
FieldFlags: 2
FieldValue: Kevin
FieldJustification: Left
```

Comment: Check that the permissions on `pdftk`, the PDF file you're trying to access, the folder that it's in, and the "current working directory" (where your output file will go, since you haven't provided a full path for it) are all such that your web service (e.g. Apache or nginx) can access them.

Answer (score 0):

You must install pdftk on your server then you can simply use        `pdftk`        instead of `/usr/bin/pdftk`

```
/usr/bin/pdftk /home/www/public_html/webroot/tmp/client_import_form_filled.pdf 
dump_data_fields_utf8 2>&1
```

to

```
pdftk /home/www/public_html/webroot/tmp/client_import_form_filled.pdf 
dump_data_fields_utf8 2>&1
```